# How to ignore all *.php requests coming to RoR project in apache server?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-2.2

Requests like unwanted .php files hitting my ROR production log

Example:

> [2019-08-07T03:42:45.415176 #32608]  INFO -- : Started GET "/java.php"
>   for 213.74.248.28 at 2019-08-07 03:42:45 -0400 F,
>   [2019-08-07T03:42:45.419677 #32608] FATAL -- :
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/java.php"):
>
> [2019-08-07T03:42:46.006077 #32608]  INFO -- : Started GET
>   "/_query.php" for 213.74.248.28 at 2019-08-07 03:42:46 -0400 F,
>   [2019-08-07T03:42:46.011142 #32608] FATAL -- :
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_query.php"):

How can i block these *.php hits in apache? i found something in nginx.but how can i block in apache?
Also, i found a 'rack-attack' gem file to block. since I'm using ruby 2.2 the gem is not supporting.

How can i get rid of this?

Comment: you may redirect to some common page like not found

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.aspx|\.asp|\.php|\.jsp|\.cgi|bitrix|wp\-content)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```